# Hide a nav menu item based on get_user_meta results

Tags: php, conditional-content, user-meta

I'm trying to hide a navigation menu item under certain circumstances. Specifically, if a user is logged in AND has already registered their product bar code, I want to hide the 'Register Kit' link (which has a class of 'ac-regkit').

Below is the PHP I've added to the head section of header.php, just before wp_head();.

```
/* If User is loggied in, hide LOG IN and SIGN UP links */
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { ?>
    <style>
        .ac-login { display: none; }
        .ac-signup { display: none; }
    </style>

    /*If user has not yet registered their DNA Test Kit, show link */
    <?php
        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
        $user_id = $current_user;
        $key = 'redeem_code';
        $single = true;
        $ac-barcode = wp_get_user_meta( $user_id, $key, $single);
        if ( $ac-barcode = '' ) { ?>
        <style>
            .ac-regkit { display: inline; font-weight: bold; }
            .ac-regkit a { color: red; }
        </style>
    <?php }; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

> **Server Error**
>   The website encountered an error while retrieving 
>   http://athleticode.com/. It may be down for maintenance
>   or configured incorrectly.

I'm not an expert in PHP, so I'm sure it's a syntax error or something like that -- and there is probably a better way to achieve this result -- so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It should be noted that the default CSS for .ac-regkit is 'display: none;'...and there is some redundancy in the variables above. Changed to `$user_id = wp_get_current_user();`.

Comment: A simple PHP error (syntax or runtime) should not result in a server error. Did you change anything else, for example in your `.htaccess` file? [Enable `WP_DEBUG`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Debug) to see detailed error messages.

Comment: @Jan Fabry: If the php is correct, this defies logic...because everything works fine with just the **is_user_logged_in** section and not the **get_user_meta** part. There has to be something wrong with the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd have 2 menus, and show the 2nd only if the user meet criteria. Then, use CSS to show both menus like its only one.

I think it's the easiest way. And you have the benefit that the items aren't really there, not just hidden.

Comment: @Daniel Dvorkin: Thanks for the response. That's a good suggestion, but even in that event I need to have a PHP conditional statement determining whether or not the current user has already registered their kit. Any idea why that isn't working, based on the code above?

Comment: Yes, the function name wp_get_user_meta is incorrect. Try get_user_meta http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta

Comment: and you should have define('WP_DEBUG', true); in wp-config while developing in order to see details of your errors

Comment: @Daniel Dvorkin: Thanks again, but I've tried 'get_user_meta' as well...no dice. The site is live, with customer traffic coming in due to the client's marketing campaign, so I'll have to wait until the wee hours to debug it I guess.

Comment: Try to get a comprensive detail of the error. Maybe a error.log in your site root? Better yet, try to get a local copy of the site in your machine to dev / debug.

Comment: I spotted another error besides the get_user_meta: $user_id = $current_user; should be $user_id = $current_user->ID;

Comment: And another one: $ac-barcode = '' in the if should be $ac-barcode == ''

Answer (score 0):

In case this was your real code and not just an example, replace it with the following one. Btw: [`<!-- this is a html comment -->`](http://htmlhelp.com/reference/wilbur/misc/comment.html) and [`<?php /* this is */ # like this or // that a php comment ?>`](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/comment.php).

```
<?php 
// Note: I moved all php-Comments inside the php tags. 
/* If User is loggied in, hide LOG IN and SIGN UP links */
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) 
{ 
?>
    <style>
        .ac-login { display: none; }
        .ac-signup { display: none; }
    </style>

    <?php
    /* If user has not yet registered their DNA Test Kit, show link */
        $current_user = get_currentuserinfo(); // THIS IS THE FUNCTION YOU NEED
        $user_id = $current_user->ID;
        $key = 'redeem_code';
        $single = true;
        $ac_barcode = wp_get_user_meta( $user_id, $key, $single);
        if ( empty( $ac_barcode ) ) { // YOU COULD TRY if ( ! $ac-barcode ) TOO
?>
        <style>
            .ac-regkit { display: inline; font-weight: bold; }
            .ac-regkit a { color: red; }
        </style>
<?php 
    } // removed ";"
}?>
```

Comment: This was very helpful, thanks! Unfortunately, I'm still getting the error. Everything works fine when I just have this: **<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { ?>
 <style>
  .ac-login { display: none; }
  .ac-signup { display: none; }
  .ac-regkit { display: inline; font-weight: bold; }
  .ac-regkit a { color: red; }
 </style>
<?php } ?>** ...but that doesn't hide the Register link.

Comment: Take Firebug AddOn for FireFox and search for an ID or class to hide it.

Comment: I've created the class (.ac-regkit)...but I'm trying to hide it only if the current logged in user has a non-empty value in their 'redeem_code' usermeta field. I'm just not writing the conditional PHP statement correctly and can't figure it out... :-/

Comment: a) See Edits and comments b) You must not use "`-`" in php variables - use `"_"` instead.

Answer (score 0):

[`wp_get_current_user()` returns the complete user *object*](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user), so your next line should not be `$user_id = $current_user`, but `$user_id = $current_user->ID`.

I understand you can't enable `WP_DEBUG` on a live site, and this might be the reason you get a "generic" error message when something goes wrong, but have you looked at the options to write PHP error messages to a log file instead? This way the user won't see the errors but you can. Developing without seeing error messages is almost impossible.